# custom checkbox doesn't check

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to customize my checkboxes, I've tried a few different tutorials, but for every single one of them, I'm still unable to check or uncheck.

Here's my code so far : 
https://jsfiddle.net/NecroSyri/behgLox0/10/

I'm using vanilla css and html, there's js too but it's unrelated to the checkboxes, I've tried to comment it just in case, same result.

```
redrawCheckboxes(); //this function create the elements that replaces the checkboxes, but that's all
```

Anyone has an idea what's keeping the click to check/uncheck the inputs ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the `onclick` event of the collapseables doesn't interfere with the `onchange` event of the checkbox? Can you attempt to check one of your custom checkboxes without the code that is responsible for collapsing / uncollapsing?

Comment: Yes, as I said I tried to comment all the js (except the one that add the elements), but it didn't changed

Comment: you have not added any event listener to `.checkmark` so how you expect click event from it?

Comment: I don't know, but all the tutorials I've seen didn't used any js, I tought it would pass the clic to the checkbox and the js would make it look like it's checked ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found another way to actually change the checkbox design instead of redrawing it :

https://jsfiddle.net/NecroSyri/behgLox0/17/

most of it is here :

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your jsFiddle and tried a few things.

I commented those lines in your CSS

```
.tree input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
```

to understand how you binded your checkbox to your custom ones.

I discovered that when you click on the original checkbox, your customs ones are well binded. But not the opposite.
Indeed, I see no trace of an `onClick` listener is you JS. But I'm really a noob in Vanilla, so maybe I'm missing something.

But in my opinion, I would add something like this in your `redraw()` method :

```
function redrawCheckboxes(){
document.querySelectorAll('.tree input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(cbox){
    var cmark = document.createElement('i');
    var newbox = cbox;
    var parentElem = cbox.parentElement;
    parentElem.prepend(cmark);
    parentElem.prepend(newbox);
    cmark.classList.add('checkmark');
    cmark.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        cmark.previousElementSibling.checked = !cmark.previousElementSibling.checked;
    });
});
```

}

I'm sure you'll find a way to clean those 3 last lines of code.
But still : it should do the job.

Happy coding